# Getting 'Access denied' when calling REST service

Tags: rest, restsharp

I'm building a small app that consumes a REST service.

The REST service expects that the URL i interact with always have the API key as an URL parameter.

So no matter if i GET, POST, UPDATE or DELETE, my URL should always contain be something like this:

`https://rest.service.tld:443/list?api_key=MY-KEY`

`https://rest.service.tld:443/lists/1/profiles/search?api_key=MY-KEY`

I tried with the sample code from RestSharp webpage, but it get the statuscode `Access Denied`

Here's my code:

```
  // Create client
  var client = new RestClient( "https://rest.service.tld:443" );
  client.Authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator( "api_key", "MY-KEY", "", "" );

  // GET list of items
  var requestLists = new RestRequest( "lists", Method.GET );
  IRestResponse<List<ListResponse>> listResponse = client.Execute<List<ListResponse>>( requestLists ); // Returns the correct list

  // POST search
  var requestProfiles = new RestRequest( "lists/1/profiles/search", Method.POST );
  requestProfiles.AddParameter( "Criteria", "{\"email\":\my@email.tld\"}" );

  IRestResponse profileResponse = client.Execute( requestProfiles ); // Returns 'Access Denied' status code
```

As far as i can tell, the `POST` method doesn't contain the correct querystring, instead my `api_key` is added as a parameter in the `POST`.

Is there a way to keep my `API_KEY` in the Querystring like i need it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the api_key is added as a normal parameter, you need to explicitly enforce that you want the parameter to be embedded into the URL, by setting the ParameterType as follows:

```
var requestProfiles = new RestRequest( "lists/1/profiles/search{api_key}", Method.POST );

requestProfiles.AddParameter( "Criteria", "{\"email\":\my@email.tld\"}" );

requestProfiles.AddParameter( "api_key", MY-KEY, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
```

More info [here](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Recommended-Usage)